# Semantic Analysis Error

Tags: sql

What wrong I am doing with this query, I always get the error whenever I try to execute it.

```
SELECT
   t1.buyer_id,
   t1.item_id,
   t1.created_time,
   t2.product_id,
   t2.timestamps
FROM
   TestingTable1 t1
   JOIN
   (
   SELECT
      user_id,
      prod_and_ts.product_id as product_id,
      prod_and_ts.timestamps as timestamps
   FROM 
      TestingTable2 
      LATERAL VIEW explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as prod_and_ts
   ) t2
   ON(t1.buyer_id = t2.user_id)
WHERE
   (t1.item_id <> t2.product_id)
   OR (unix_timestamp(t1.created_time) <> t2.timestamps);
```

This is the error I get-

```
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 13:6 Invalid Table Alias or 
Column Reference prod_and_ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but Lateral View Syntax

```
LATERAL VIEW udtf(expression) tableAlias AS columnAlias (',' columnAlias)*
```

In your case prod_and_ts it's a columnAlias, not tableAlias and you cannot use prod_and_ts.product_id. Instead try to use just prod_and_ts.

Comment: According to you what changes I need to make? Sorry, I was not able to understand.

Comment: syntax like that, but it should be corrected for your multiple column result. SELECT      user_id, product_id FROM  TestingTable2 LATERAL VIEW explode(purchased_item) exploded_table as product_id